# What is bitly='BITLY_PROCESSED' in <a> tag?

Tags: html, facebook, bit.ly

While i was inspecting facebook html code through with firebug in Chrome, i found this tag :

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/?ref=logo" title="Home" bitly="BITLY_PROCESSED"/>
```

What is the bitly attribute? Anyone has an idea?

:)

Comment: In my opinion, that's some dark magic from facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets added by the bit.ly plug-in (and perhaps some others) when it examines links (see http://bit.ly/pages/tools form more on that). If you don't have that plug-in yoruself, then it may be that someone somewhere along the line did.

Answer (score 1):

[bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) offers URL redirection service with real-time link tracking, or in other words URL shortener, so I am guessing you have it's plugin installed.